# empty the ram after a curl call

Tags: php, curl

I'm downloading large files with curl, but i don't think the buffer is emptied because the ram mileage keeps increasing until it reaches 100%, here is the code that i use.

if i close and open curl will that help??

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);

while($start_range <= $end_range) {
if(($start_range + 999999) > $end_range) $range = $start_range.'-';
else $range = $start_range.'-'.($start_range + 999999);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, $url);

curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,array("ETag: $rddash"));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $cookie);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $cookie);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RANGE,$range);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.8.1.1) Gecko/20061204 Firefox/2.0.0.1');
if ($tmp = curl_exec($ch))  $start_range +=1000000;
echo $tmp;
flush();
} 
curl_close($ch);
```

Comment: Maybe I missed something important but what are you trying to do with so many cURL requests inside a **very** long loop? Perform a DDoS attack with cURL?

Comment: not at all man, i said it in the very first sentence, i'm trying to download large file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
curl_close(), takes a Curl resource as its only parameter,   
closes the Curl session, then frees up the associated memory.
```

Comment: so what you are saying i have to close the curl everytime and reopen it again??